# How to get slug for a submit form?

Tags: django

I have form added to SingleStory() view which is processed by AddTask(). But I have a problem, I don't know how to get a slug for this: form.instance.story = Story.objects.get(slug=slug)? Do you have any advices how to do it?

Now I get error: "global name 'slug' is not defined".

Here is my views.py:

```
class SingleStory(View):
    model = Story

    def get(self, request, slug):
        story = Story.objects.get(slug=slug)
        tasks = Task.objects.filter(story=story)
        form = AddTaskForm
        total_time = 0
        for task in tasks:
            total_time += task.iteration
        return render(request, 'single-story.html', locals())


class AddTask(CreateView):
    model = Task
    form_class = AddTaskForm
    template_name = 'add-task.html'
    link_name = 'add-task'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('all-stories')


    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.story = Story.objects.get(slug=slug)
        form.save()
        return super(AddTask, self).form_valid(form)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^add-story/', AddStory.as_view(), name='add-story'),
url(r'^add-task/', AddTask.as_view(), name='add-task'),
url(r'^(?P<slug>.*)/$', SingleStory.as_view(), name='single-story',),
```

Comment: Where is the slug supposed to be coming from? What does your URL look like?

Comment: I added urls.py file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with anything in Python, you can't reference a variable that is not available in the current scope. In this case, there is no local or global variable called 'slug', hence your error.

Django's class-based views put strings extracted from the URL into the instance's `args` list or `kwargs` dictionary. For this to work in your AddTask view, you would need to capture the slug in the URL for that view, as you do for the SingleStory view:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>.*)/add-task/', AddTask.as_view(), name='add-task'),
```

and then use it in the view:

```
form.instance.story = Story.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
```